# Fail to initiate Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I created my kafkaConsumer consumer config programmatically and the application is deployed correctly:-

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
MosSerdes.MosKeySerde.class); 
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
MosSerdes.MosValueSerde.class);`
```

But now I need to specify the above values via the application.YAML file , I specified the changes as below :-

```
default-key-serde: com.mos.core.kafkaConfig.serdes.MosSerdes.MosKeySerde
default-value-serde: com.mos.core.kafkaConfig.serdes.MosSerdes.MosValueSerde`
```

It gives me the below error:-

```
Failed to start bean
org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry';
nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: 
Failed to construct kafka consumer

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:718)
```

It gives a null pointer exception at this line in the 'KafkaConsumer' class because these values are not getting set correctly, how to correctly initialize in the application.YAML file

```
this.valueDeserializer.configure(config.originals(Collections.singletonMap(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId)), false);
```

```
public class MosSerdes extends Serdes {

    /**
     * Serializer/Deserializer for mos event key.
     */
    public static final class MosKeySerde extends WrapperSerde<String> {

        public MosKeySerde() {
            super(Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().deserializer());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Serializer/Deserializer for mos event value.
     */
    public static final class MosValueSerde extends WrapperSerde<CommonAlert> {

        public MosValueSerde() {
            super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>());
        }

public class Serdes {

    static public class WrapperSerde<T> implements Serde<T> {
        final private Serializer<T> serializer;
        final private Deserializer<T> deserializer;

        public WrapperSerde(Serializer<T> serializer, Deserializer<T> deserializer) {
            this.serializer = serializer;
            this.deserializer = deserializer;
        }
```

The issue is these values are not correctly defined , how can i define these values correctly in application.yaml file

```
default-key-serde: com.mos.core.kafkaConfig.serdes.MosSerdes.MosKeySerde
default-value-serde: com.mos.core.kafkaConfig.serdes.MosSerdes.MosValueSerde
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your complete YAML.

What makes you think that `default-*-serde` are valid properties?

It's `default.key.serde` and `default.value.serde`.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#streamsconfigs_default.value.serde

If you are using Spring Boot, you need to set such properties via https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.streams.properties, e.g.

spring.kafka.streams.properties.[default.value.serde]: ...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties